# ImportError: DLL load failed: mediapipe

Tags: python, mediapipe

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/pythonProject2/name.py", line 2, in <module>
    import mediapipe as mp
  File "D:\pythonProject2\app_d\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from mediapipe.python import *
  File "D:\pythonProject2\app_d\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from mediapipe.python._framework_bindings import resource_util
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you have not described your problem and its attempts to solve it in great detail, but I can offer this option:

Try installing this:

```
pip install msvc-runtime
```

Also install OpenCV to avoid errors.